# Deploy Spring Boot App to Swisscom Cloud with New Relic Java Agent

Tags: newrelic, swisscomdev

I am unsuccessful in deploying a really simple (one endpoint) spring boot app to the swisscom cloud with the new relic java agent.

Here is the main dependency found in pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
      <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Here is the manifest.yml:

```
    applications:
    - name: newrelicdemocf
      memory: 512M
      instances: 1
      buildpack: java_buildpack_v3
      path: target/newrelicdemocf.jar
```

Locally I am able to start the app with the new relic java agent as it is explained [how to run](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/installation/install-java-agent) and [how to install via maven](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/java-agent/additional-installation/maven-installation-java).

I have found that swisscom supports new relic for php applications, but I haven't found any reference for spring boot apps.

The [java build pack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/releases/tag/v3.19) documentation states it supports new relic, but I also haven't found a way to bind the two.

Is there a way to run the new relic java agent with a Spring boot app on Swisscom cloud and if so, what steps am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leverage the java buildpack new relic support, you do not have to include the agent in your application jar. All you have to do is to configure your new relic service details as a user provided service. See the description in the docs:

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/framework-new_relic_agent.md#user-provided-service-optional

Comment: Matthias, I have done this as well. I created a user provided service called _newrelicservice_, and added the credentials as:
key: "licence_key"
value: "my_licence_key"
without the quotes. However, I didn't see my app in the Newrelic dashboard. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Perhaps it's the English vs US version of the word licence. So that was it.